# Regex Pattern Match toString() in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm looking for some help with matching a pattern for a string (tostring() generated):

`MyObject{nothingSpecial='Word1', secretData='Word2', privateEmail='Word3'}`

I wanted a pattern that can match on the Word1, Word3. So I came up with:

`(?x)(["]?(nothingSpecial|secretData)["]?\s*[:=]{1}\s*["]?)(?:[^"\n,]+)`

That worked but now I need to step it up so I can match on the oject name too e.g. `MyObject`

### Examples:

1. Don't match since it's not `MyObject`: YourObject{nothingSpecial='Word1', secretData='Word2', privateEmail='Word3'}
2. Match to MyObject so look for nothingSpecial & privateEmail: **MyObject** { **nothingSpecial='Word1'**, secretData='Word2', **privateEmail='Word3'**}
3. Don't match since it's not `MyObject`: TheirObject{nothingSpecial='Word1', secretData='Word2', privateEmail='Word3'}

Truthfully, I've never been great a RegEx so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You state that your pattern matches Word1 and Word 3, but can you explain how that matches? In this example it does not match https://regex101.com/r/0suKw8/1 How should we interpret the examples? Does you want to pattern to match the 3 bold words?

Comment: Ack! Sorry, you are right. I should have jsut copy/pasted it. It should be (?x)(["]?(nothingSpecial|secretData)["]?\s*[:=]{1}\s*["]?)(?:[^"\n,]+). I'll update the question and clarify.

Comment: You could use 2 capture groups https://regex101.com/r/J7kFmA/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the 3 words, you could make use if the `\G` anchor

```
(?:\b(MyObject)\h*\{\h*(?=[^{}]*})|\G(?!^))(?:(?:nothingSpecial|privateEmail)='([^'\n,]+)'|[^\s=]+='[^'\n,]*')(?:,\h*)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS4DBz/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/YSHEHs)

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\b(MyObject)\h*\{\h*` Capture `MyObject` in **group 1** and match `{`
  - `(?=[^{}]*})`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:nothingSpecial|privateEmail)=` Match either `nothingSpecial` or `privateEmail` followed by `=`
  - `'([^'\n,]+)'` Capture **group 2** Match any char except `'` a newline or comma between single quotes
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\s=]+='[^'\n,]*'` Match a key value pair with single quotes
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?:,\h*)?` Optionally match a comma and horizontal whitespace chars

Comment: Thank you very much. I swear my brain just isn't wired for RegEx.